# Is there a ternary or coalesce operator for unwrapping optionals in Swift?

Tags: swift

For example, instead of doing:

```
class Person {
  var name: String
  init(_ name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

if let unwrappedName = p.name {
  var greeting = “Hello “ + unwrappedName
} else {
  var greeting = “Hello stranger”
}
```

Could I do this instead?

```
var upwrappedName = p.name ?? "default"
```

Or:

```
var unwrappedName = p.name ? p.name : "default"
```

Comment: What happened when you _tried_ it?

Answer (score 1):

"The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must match the type that is stored inside a." The documentation can be found [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) So you can use the nil coalescing operator or even the ternary operator if you want if your statement before the operator is `p.name != nil` as your statement

Comment: Not the ternary operator. `p.name` is not a Bool.